# How to store a 5MB file preview in a DB

Tags: mysql, sql, redis, database-performance

I have an application that allows to parse a file. Let's say they want to parse a 1GB csv file. How the application works is it stores a 5MB preview of the file -- just the first 5MB of data in the file -- and allows them to apply settings to it, for example: what the `separator` is, what the `quotechar` is, etc.

My question is what would be the best way to store this data? The simplest example I can think of would be:

```
- file_id (id)
- filename (varchar)
- file_url (varchar)
- [various file settings]
- data (longtext or blob)
```

In this way, whenever a user wants to save a new setting, we would apply the transformation to the `data` that is stored.

However, I see two issues with this:

1. The row itself would be very large, and would probably be stored better like this:

   `file`

   - file_id (id)
   - filename (varchar)
   - file_url (varchar)
   - [various file settings]

   `file_data`

   - file_id (FK)
   - data

In this way, only if I query that table directly would I need to load all that data.

2. It takes a non-trivial amount of time to load 5MB of data over the network (whether it's a link or a blob). For this I was thinking to use something like a redis cache for the `file_id:5_mb_data`, but I would eventually need a **ton** of space for this.

What would be a good way to store the above so that I can generate a file preview on-the-fly in a quick way?

I'm storing the files on GCS, and in order to get any of it (whether the full file or 5mb of it) I need to download it locally.

Comment: I believe MySQL already stores things like blobs separately. As long as you're code is not carelessly selecting * all over the place that part should not be an issue. ...and if you have the file url, and continuous access to it; why not just load the preview directly from the file instead of copying part of it into the db?

Comment: @Uueerdo that's a good idea -- it seems I overlooked the easiest way to do it -- just store the 5MB file locally and access that directly each time I need it.

Comment: @Uueerdo does my answer below describe what you're suggesting? If so, I think it's a great solution -- thanks

Comment: I was actually thinking more along the lines of the database client, or server process, using the stored url to open the original file and get the first 5MB; I haven't had much occasion to store files or file references in the databases I've worked with, but I understand storing them locally on or accessible to the server process, and just having the database track them, is the standard solution used.

Answer (score 0):

As Uueerdo suggested, it might make most sense to store the preview of the file locally, for example named `md5_checksum` to ensure uniqueness. In this way, you don't need to worry about having a centrally located cache (such as redis), and opening and reading a 5MB file only takes about 1/1000th of a second:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("with open('5mbfile', 'r') as f: _=f.read()", number=1000) / 1000
0.0011376328468322755
```